# Fastest way to search text in multiple files?

Tags: c#, regex, string, richtextbox

I need to find some text in around 120 text files, I want to know which will be the best and fastest way to search text. Am I supposed to read each file in a RichTextBox then use its methods to search text or should I be reading those files into a string variable and then searching using regular expressions?

I think the major factor behind performance is to find a way so that there is no need to loop through the lines which have already been tested for match. Is there any way to find all the matches in a file in one go? Does anyone knows a way to find matches in text files as Visual Studio does? It searched 200 text files for match in around 800-1000 Milliseconds. I think it makes use of multiple threads to accomplish this.

Comment: Instead of loading each file in a RichTextBox, you can just load in a string object and work with it.

Comment: Search what? Without context it is impossible to answer. and `RichTextBox` is irrelevant here.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel ,suppose I have 120 code files and I want to search `public` in those files and reteiive their positions as well ?

Comment: [Lucene.Net](http://lucenenet.apache.org/)

Comment: What will be the file size?

Comment: Are the files large? What kind of searching do you want to do: exact match, contains, pattern? Do you want to read the files again and again for each search or build a word index to be searched multiple times?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel ,each file is greater than 1 MB in size and contains more than 70000-80000 words.

Comment: Greater than 1mb but what will be the max size of files?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel ,Not more than 2 MB.

Comment: @Alex ,the search depends upon User's choice and for rest i'll go with you.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel ,I've updated the question,please read it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description (120 files, 70K-80K words, 1-2 MB per file), it would seem the best approach is to read the files once and build an index that can be searched. I have included an example below to illustrate how such a thing can be done, but that may be of limited use to you if you need more complex search term matching than finding an exact term or a prefixed term.

If you need more complex text search matching (while getting good performance), I would advise you to look into the excellent Lucene library, that was built specifically for this purpose.

```
public struct WordLocation
{
    public WordLocation(string fileName, int lineNumber, int wordIndex)
    {
        FileName = fileName;
        LineNumber = lineNumber;
        WordIndex = wordIndex;
    }
    public readonly string FileName; // file containing the word.
    public readonly int LineNumber;  // line within the file.
    public readonly int WordIndex;   // index within the line.
}

public struct WordOccurrences
{
    private WordOccurrences(int nOccurrences, WordLocation[] locations)
    {
        NumberOfOccurrences = nOccurrences;
        Locations = locations;
    }

    public static readonly WordOccurrences None = new WordOccurrences(0, new WordLocation[0]);

    public static WordOccurrences FirstOccurrence(string fileName, int lineNumber, int wordIndex)
    {
        return new WordOccurrences(1, new [] { new WordLocation(fileName, lineNumber, wordIndex) });
    }

    public WordOccurances AddOccurrence(string fileName, int lineNumber, int wordIndex)
    {
        return new WordOccurrences(
            NumberOfOccurrences + 1, 
            Locations
                .Concat(
                    new [] { new WordLocation(fileName, lineNumber, wordIndex) })
                .ToArray());
    }

    public readonly int NumberOfOccurrences;
    public readonly WordLocation[] Locations;
}

public interface IWordIndexBuilder
{
    void AddWordOccurrence(string word, string fileName, int lineNumber, int wordIndex);
    IWordIndex Build();
}

public interface IWordIndex
{
    WordOccurrences Find(string word);
}

public static class BuilderExtensions
{
    public static IWordIndex BuildIndexFromFiles(this IWordIndexBuilder builder, IEnumerable<FileInfo> wordFiles)
    {
        var wordSeparators = new char[] {',', ' ', '\t', ';' /* etc */ };
        foreach (var file in wordFiles)
        {
            var lineNumber = 1;
            using (var reader = file.OpenText())
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var words = reader
                         .ReadLine() 
                         .Split(wordSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                         .Select(f => f.Trim());

                    var wordIndex = 1;
                    foreach (var word in words)
                        builder.AddWordOccurrence(word, file.FullName, lineNumber, wordIndex++);

                    lineNumber++;
                }
            }
        }
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Then the simplest index implementation (that can only do an exact match lookup) uses a dictionary internally:

```
public class DictionaryIndexBuilder : IIndexBuilder
{
    private Dictionary<string, WordOccurrences> _dict;

    private class DictionaryIndex : IWordIndex 
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, WordOccurrences> _dict;

        public DictionaryIndex(Dictionary<string, WordOccurrences> dict)
        {
            _dict = dict;
        }
        public WordOccurrences Find(string word)
        {
           WordOccurrences found;
           if (_dict.TryGetValue(word, out found);
               return found;
           return WordOccurrences.None;
        }
    }

    public DictionaryIndexBuilder(IEqualityComparer<string> comparer)
    {
        _dict = new Dictionary<string, WordOccurrences>(comparer);
    }
    public void AddWordOccurrence(string word, string fileName, int lineNumber, int wordIndex)
    {
        WordOccurrences current;
        if (!_dict.TryGetValue(word, out current))
            _dict[word] = WordOccurrences.FirstOccurrence(fileName, lineNumber, wordIndex);
        else
            _dict[word] = current.AddOccurrence(fileName, lineNumber, wordIndex);
    }
    public IWordIndex Build()
    {
        var dict = _dict;
        _dict = null;
        return new DictionaryIndex(dict);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var builder = new DictionaryIndexBuilder(EqualityComparer<string>.Default);
var index = builder.BuildIndexFromFiles(myListOfFiles);
var matchSocks = index.Find("Socks");
```

If you also want to do prefix lookups, implement an index builder/index class that uses a sorted dictionary (and change the `IWordIndex.Find` method to return multiple matches, or add a new method to the interface for finding partial/pattern matches).

If you want to do more complex lookups, go for something like Lucence.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I will if I where you:

1- I'll load all files path to a list of string.

2- I'll create a new list to store files path that match my search term.

3- I'll loop foreach in Files list and search for my term then I'll add the matched file to the new list.

```
string searchTerm = "Some terms";
    string[] MyFilesList = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\txtDirPath\", "*.txt");
    List<string> FoundedSearch=new List<string>();
    foreach (string filename in MyFilesList)
    {
        string textFile = File.ReadAllText(filename);
        if (textFile.Contains(searchTerm))
        {
            FoundedSearch.Add(filename);
        }
    }
```

then you can deal with the List:FoundedSearch what ever you want.

**by the way:**

I don't know the best answer but the performance will be very well until 800 text file with 1000 word per file
you can find the performance pretty well with [this chart](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_9xVo3hVKsko/RfkPmkEjsOI/AAAAAAAAARk/_DUwYoGtXDs/s1600/Chart-Array.png)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to search every file for the same string. You could use a `compiled regex` for each search.

```
string searchTerm = "searchWord";
Regex rx = new Regex(String.Format("\b{0}\b", searchTerm), RegexOptions.Compiled);
List<string> filePaths = new List<string>();

foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
   string allText = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
   var matches = rx.Matches(allText);             
   //rest of code
}
```

You'd have to benchmark performance but I imagine the major bottleneck will be the opening and reading of the file from the disk. You could look into [Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) if that turns out to be the case. Alternatively, depending on what you're ultimately trying to do, a dedicated text searcher such as `Lucene.Net` (as I4V mentioned in the comments) might be more suitable.